# Why is RemoveAll(x => x.Condition) removing all my records?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm working on creating a filter for a collection of employees. In order to do this I initially fetch a raw collection of all employees. I clone this list so I can iterate over the original list but remove items from the second list.

For each filter I have, I build a collection of employee ids that pass the filter. Having gone through all filters I then attempt to remove everything that isn't contained in any of these lists from the cloned list.

However for some reason, whenever I attempt to do this using .RemoveAll(), all records seemed to be removed and I can't figure out why.

Here is a stripped down version of the method I'm using, with only 1 filter applied:

```
public List<int> GetFilteredEmployeeIds(int? brandId)
{

    List<int> employeeIds = GetFilteredEmployeeIdsBySearchTerm();

    List<int> filteredEmployeeIds = employeeIds.Clone();

    // Now filter the results based on which checkboxes are ticked
    foreach (var employeeId in employeeIds)
    {
        // 3rd party API used to get values - please ignore for this example
        Member m = new Member(employeeId);

        if (m.IsInGroup("Employees"))
        {
            int memberBrandId = Convert.ToInt32(m.getProperty("brandID").Value);

            // Filter by brand
            List<int> filteredEmployeeIdsByBrand = new List<int>();

            if (brandId != null)
            {
                if (brandId == memberBrandId)
                    filteredEmployeeIdsByBrand.Add(m.Id);

                var setToRemove = new HashSet<int>(filteredEmployeeIdsByBrand);
                filteredEmployeeIds.RemoveAll(x => !setToRemove.Contains(x));
            }
        }
    }

    return filteredEmployeeIds;
}
```

As you can see, I'm basically attempting to remove all records from the cloned record set, wherever the id doesn't match in the second collection. However for some reason every record seems to be getting removed.

Anybody know why?

P.S: Just to clarify, I have put in logging to check the values throughout the process and there are records appearing in the second list, however for whatever reason they're not getting matched in the RemoveAll()

Thanks

Comment: Personally, I would use a debugger and step through the code, inspect variables, and all those things…

Comment: `filteredEmployeeIds.RemoveAll(x => !setToRemove.Contains(x));` should there really be a `!`?

Comment: `!setToRemove.Contains(x)` You're removing everything that _isn't_ in the list of items to remove. Is that the way it's supposed to be?

Comment: Yes that was the intended purpose

Answer (score 2):

Ok only minutes after posting this I realised what I did wrong: The scoping is incorrect. What it *should've* been was like so:

```
public List<int> GetFilteredEmployeeIds(int? brandId)
        {
            List<int> employeeIds = GetFilteredEmployeeIdsBySearchTerm();

            List<int> filteredEmployeeIds = employeeIds.Clone();
            List<int> filteredEmployeeIdsByBrand = new List<int>();

            // Now filter the results based on which checkboxes are ticked
            foreach (var employeeId in employeeIds)
            {
                Member m = new Member(employeeId);

                if (m.IsInGroup("Employees"))
                {
                    int memberBrandId = Convert.ToInt32(m.getProperty("brandID").Value);

                    // Filter by brand
                    if (brandId != null)
                    {
                        if (brandId == memberBrandId)
                            filteredEmployeeIdsByBrand.Add(m.Id);
                    }
                }
            }

            var setToRemove = new HashSet<int>(filteredEmployeeIdsByBrand);
            filteredEmployeeIds.RemoveAll(x => !setToRemove.Contains(x));

            return filteredEmployeeIds;
        }
```

Essentially the removal of entries needed to be done *outside* the loop of the employee ids :-)

Comment: Great, you got your answer so quickly bu urself. And thanx for sharing with us.

Comment: haha, thanks. I'm just annoyed it was something so simple that I missed :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know that you said your example was stripped down, so maybe this wouldn't suit, but could you do something like the following:

```
    public List<int> GetFilteredEmployeeIds(int? brandId)
    {
        List<int> employeeIds = GetFilteredEmployeeIdsBySearchTerm();
        return employeeIds.Where(e => MemberIsEmployeeWithBrand(e, brandId)).ToList();
    }

    private bool MemberIsEmployeeWithBrand(int employeeId, int? brandId)
    {
        Member m = new Member(employeeId);

        if (!m.IsInGroup("Employees"))
        {
            return false;
        }

        int memberBrandId = Convert.ToInt32(m.getProperty("brandID").Value);
        return brandId == memberBrandId;
    }
```

I've just done that off the top of my head, not tested, but if all you need to do is filter the employee ids, then maybe you don't need to clone the original list, just use the Where function to do the filtering on it directly??

Please someone let me know if i've done something blindingly stupid!!